# Mechanical vibration of objects

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vibration

Do you happen to know relevant references in the literature that model the mechanical vibrations of a solid object (preferably antennas) by means of complex representations as a function of time?, i.e. can we say that the radial displacement can be modeled as

$$ r(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}{a_i \exp\left(-j b t \cos(\phi_i)\right)}$$

where $a_i, b,$ and $\phi_i$ are constant independent of time $t$ and $j$ is the complex number such that $j^2 = -1$.

Comment: Would [FEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) combined with [spectral decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) work for you?

Comment: Try one of Meirovitch's textbooks

Comment: You can not generalize with all structural antenna for dampening Q , f and wind resistance , moment of inertia etc and this equation would vary according to what it needs to be for phase jitter.

Answer (score 0):

No, I didn't check but I don't think these type of equations would be in a mechanical vibrations textbook mainly because a forcing function or initial displacement is not present, nor is the distance from the base of the antenna. In addition to mechanical vibrations equations, Finite element analysis can provide radial displacement. Textbooks links are below:

[https://www.amazon.com/Mechanical-Vibrations-6th-Singiresu-Rao/dp/013436130X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1519437095&sr=8-1&keywords=mechanical+vibrations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013436130X)

[https://www.amazon.com/Schaums-Outline-Mechanical-Vibrations-Graham/dp/0070340412/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1519437095&sr=8-6&keywords=mechanical+vibrations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070340412)

Comment: Is it possible to cite references where I can find the model you're talking about. Thanks.